# Left Join web2py

Tags: web2py

I tried this query and gives me an error.
dtms_documents.dtype, 'reference dtms_type'

And this is the query I used:

```
    comms = db().select(db.dtms_documents.ALL, db.dtms_type.ALL, 
    left=db.dtms_type.on(db.dtms_documents.dtype==db.dtms_type.id))
```

https://ibb.co/rdv6ZkZ

Comment: Instead:
     newdata = {"ref_no":comm.ref_no,"details":comm.details}
Use:
     newdata = {"ref_no":comm.[tablename].ref_no,"details":comm.[tablename].details}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a join and include fields in the select from both tables, to refer to a given field value within a `row` object, you must use both the table name and the field name (i.e., `row.tablename.fieldname` rather than just `row.fieldname`). So, in your dictionary, instead of:

```
{'ref_no': comm.ref_no, ...}
```

it should be:

```
{'ref_no': comm.[tablename].ref_no, ...}
```

where `[tablename]` would be either `dtms_documents` or `dtms_type`, depending on which table the `ref_no` field belongs to.